# How to add password to google cloud memorystore

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, haproxy, google-cloud-memorystore

I need to access google cloud memorystore from cloud function but i know it's not supported yet, so i tried workaround to add haproxy in my kubernetes cluster and make it publicly access able using kubernetes service from type loadbalancer and forward the tcp requests to memorystore.

It works fine with me and i can connect to my memorystore instance from cloud function, but only the problem i have and i need fix for it to securing memorystore  on the haproxy level or on the memorystore level, i tried to add a password to memorystore but i found the CONFIG command is disabled.

That's my haproxy config:

```
frontend redis_frontend
   bind *:6379
   mode tcp
   option tcplog
   timeout client  1m
   default_backend redis_backend

backend redis_backend
   mode tcp
   option tcplog
   option log-health-checks
   option redispatch
   log global
   balance roundrobin
   timeout connect 10s
   timeout server 1m
   server redis_server 10.0.0.12:6379 check
```

So any suggestions ?

Comment: As you have rightly mentioned, this is currently not possible in Cloud Memorystore. However, please feel free to file a issue to enable this mechanism (https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/getting-support#file_bugs_or_feature_requests) so that we can consider in our future plans, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

We don't support network connectivity from App Engine or Cloud functions yet. We are working on adding this support in the future.

Like you found out connectivity from GKE environment is supported.

We don't support AUTH config yet, this feature is on our roadmap in near future.

Thanks for the feedback,
Prajakta

(Engineering Manager on GCP)

Comment: By near future, any ETA? We wanted to use Redis' redlock to synchronize some of the cloud functions - now I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and we will wait till this feature released and thanks again for the amazing managed Redis from google.

Comment: @Prajakta, any update on MemoryStore Auth? It's been nearly a year. Thanks.

Comment: Any update here? Facing same problem. @amohamed did you find any way around?