# Is there any way to enable Authentication and authorization for Google Memorystore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore

I am using Google Memorystore for Redis for our in-memory datastore and I am processing dataflow pipeline for processing and transforming input files and storing the processed data in Google Memorystore.

But is there any way we can enable authentication and authorization for memorystore so that other applications can access with token or other authentication mechanism?

I didn't get much info from the official documentation. However, I got the stackoverflow answer but there's no clarity.

[How to add password to google cloud memorystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122294/how-to-add-password-to-google-cloud-memorystore)

Any reference links for this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation:

[Connecting to a Redis instance](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance)

> "You can connect to the Redis instance from **any** Compute Engine VM
> instance located within the same project, region and network as the
> Redis instance."

Therefore authentication and authorization for memorystore using service accounts credentials is not supported.

A feature request was opened on this limitation:

[Implementing Authentication for Cloud Memorystore
Public](https://issuetracker.google.com/152073004)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a [firewall rules on service account](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#serviceaccounts). Like this, the authentication is the service account mounted on the VM that try to reach the memoryStore (port 6379). And the authorization is, the firewall rule itself (Allow or deny the traffic from the service account).

Comment: I am deploying my application via pods that is connecting to memorystore. But I have not added any roles in my service-account to retrieve data from memorystore but still it connects. How can we confirm that it is authenticated before connecting.

Comment: Did you define firewall rule with a service account? If so, change this service account and validate that you no longer have access to Memory store. So, as I described, the service account provide the authentication (the identity), not the authorization. For other service, authorizations are defined with IAM roles, but there, it's the firewall rule that allow or deny the request identity (with the service account)